# Typescript: Add interface information to class with decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have a decorator like this:

```
export function Entity(options?: string) {
    return (target) => {
        //do something with class(target) here
    }
}
```

and a class which can be decorated like this:

```
@Entity({someOptions: "foobar"})
export class Product {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
}
```

How can I force the id automatically without doing this:

```
interface EntityInterface {
    id: string;
}

@Entity({someOptions: "foobar"})
export class Product implements EntityInterface {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
}
```

Can the implementation of an interface added automatically by the decorator?

Answer (score 2):

Decorators can't change the structure of a class, this is by design. What you could do is use a function that takes a class as parameter and return a new class that has the extra field:

```
export function Entity(options?: string) {
  return <T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(target: T) => {
    return class extends target {
      id: string
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.id = options;
      }
    }
  }
}


export const Product = Entity("foobar")(class Product {
  public constructor(values: Partial<Product>) {

  }
  title: string;
  price: number;
});

let d = new Product({
  title: ""
});
```

You can add fields and methods inside the class derived inside the function and it will be available in the returned class, the only potential problem is that the fields/methods will not be accessible inside the class that is passed as parameter to `Entity`